# How do I make a content script load before another content script (that runs on the same event) in a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Here's a portion of my manifest.json file:

```
  "content_scripts": [ {
"js": [ "common.js", "generation.js" ],
"matches": [ "*://www.site.com/*" ],
"run_at": "document_start"
},
{
"js": [ "page_init.js" ],
"matches": [ "*://www.site.com/*" ],
"run_at": "document_start"
},
```

Here, I want to run "common.js" before "page_init.js", as common.js contains much shared code and global variables and functions that the other content scripts need to function. I have defined common.js before page_init.js in my manifest, and, in Chrome, doing this results in common.js running before all the other content scripts, which is what I need. However, in Firefox, it doesn't seem to do this.

When I run this extension in Firefox, however, page_init throws an error:

`ReferenceError:  ReferenceError: href is not defined`

"href" is a variable that's defined in common.js.

Do I need to make page_init.js run at document_end in order for common.js to fully run, or is there another way? I need them to both run at document_start.

**UPDATE:**

I managed to resolve the issue by changing the manifests contents to this:

```
 "content_scripts": [ 
{
"js": [ "common.js", "generation.js", "page_init.js" ],
"matches": [ "*://www.site.com/*" ],
"run_at": "document_start"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

From [firefox documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts#js):

> js
>
> An array of paths, relative to manifest.json, referencing JavaScript
> files that will be injected into matching pages.
>
> Files are **injected in the order given**. This means that, for example,
> if you include jQuery here followed by another content script, like
> this...

It's probably a firefox bug, you may want to report it.